# How to nest Less than and greater than in one code

Tags: vba, if-statement

Im in a dilemma here which I just cant seem to put my finger on it. You pro vba users might be able to help.

Basically I am trying to show that finished goods bottles - raw bottles has limits. as shown below.
If total has more than 208 raw bottles used for finished goods then no-go message, if less then proceed. But at the same time if 50 bottles less of raw bottles to make the finished goods then no-go message.

So If finished goods = 4000
raw bottles = 4212

Message will show 212 bottles no go message

If finished goods = 4000
raw bottles = 3949

message should show 51 bottles no go message

```
    If Abs(.Cells(21, 3)) < 208 Or Abs(.Cells(21, 3)) < -50 Then
    
        '# Display "go" message
       .Cells(7, 5) = "All good, you may proceed to enter figures in EZY."

    Else
    
        '# Display "no-go" message
        .Cells(7, 5) = "there is " & .Cells(21, 3) & " bottles less from Depal, do not enter in EZY!"
                                                    
    End If 'Check
```

I hope this makes sense. Can I nest the greater than and less than or do I type another code below it?
If I remove 'Or Abs(.Cells(21, 3)) < -50' the whole code works but only for upper limit.

Comment: Which way do you calculated the difference? Is it `Finished - Raw` or `Raw - Finished`?

Comment: it is Raw - Finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate by `Raw - Finished` Then it should be

```
If .Cells(21, 3) > 208 Or .Cells(21, 3) < -50 Then
```

Otherwise if you calculate by `Finished - Raw` then it should be

```
If .Cells(21, 3) < -208 Or .Cells(21, 3) > 50 Then
```

By using the `Abs` you remove the ability to tell whether the value is below or above the "4000".

Comment: Hi, sorry took a while to get back, have attempted these and still same result. either the 208 and above will show the error but not the below 50. and vice versa below the 50 will show but not the above 208.

Comment: Hmm it works for me. What's the formula in `.Cells(21,3)`? 
I also assume you are using a With Statement since your doing `.Cells`. Also try putting `212` then `-51` in `.Cells(21,3)` and make sure it works. I suspect it's something to do with your formula in that cell or something that's coming from it.

Comment: .Cells(21, 3) = .Cells(9, 3) - .Cells(11, 3) which is Finished - Raw

Comment: So `.Cells(21,3)` is calculated in VBA? AKA it doesn't have a formula in the cell? Also did you try the method I suggested above? Both my formulas in my answer work for either way it's calculated as I've tested them so there is something wrong with your cell or the formulas/formatting you are using. So test yourself with just putting a value in that cell or try it in a new sheet and see if it works. Also what's your `With` that your using? You could also try putting a `.Value` at the end of the `.Cells()`

Comment: Will attempt to find the errors. Its a massive workbook with many worksheets so the With is Op1. Set Op1 = Worksheet blabla so its 
With Op1

.cells...

Comment: Thank you for the big help Simon!

Answer (score 0):

In the end this worked out. Thank you!

```
    '# If D - F - Wastes is within +/- 50...
    If .Cells(21, 3) < 208 And .Cells(21, 3) > -50 Then
    
        '# Display "go" message
       .Cells(7, 5) = "All good, you may proceed to enter figures in EZY."

    Else
        '# Display "no-go" message
        .Cells(7, 5) = "there is " & .Cells(21, 3) & " bottles less from Depal, do not enter in EZY!"
                                                    
    End If 'Check
```